# PHP - Why do these emails only get sent to gmail accounts and not to others?

Tags: php, email, gmail

It seems only people with gmail accounts receives these emails:

```
function sendEmail($email, $hashid) {
    $content = "<p>x</p>";
    $fromName = "N";
    $fromEmail = "n@n.se";

    $to = $email;
    $subject = 'y';
    $message = $content;
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From:  ' . $fromName . ' <' . $fromEmail .'>' . " \r\n" .
            'Reply-To: '.  $fromEmail . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    return mail ( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
}
```

Is something wrong with the headers?

Comment: Explain what's your problem.

Comment: There is nothing that specifies only gmail. Is the email being sent from gmail account?

Comment: Depends on the headers added by the MTA, not the ones in that PHP snippet.

Comment: No it is sent from a web hosting hotel. Using the same code without $headers variables works and email is sent to any domain...

@AA Shakil - Problem is that my customer who doesn't have gmail account does not revieve my emails.

Comment: I notice that email gets sent to e.g. hotmail but it get marks as spam